# Electrical work sign convention

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, work, voltage, conventions

[image]

If I understood the correct sign convention it's as shown in the below sketch:
[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @noah Sorry. is the sketch accurate in regards to the sign  of the work?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Can you define what you mean by charge equal to $+ ve$? Is $v$ a positive integer? Also, when $ve$ is a charge, work can't be $\pm ve$, since work is not given in units of charge. You also have to specify which work you want to calculate. It is path dependent. I suppose you mean the work required to bring a particle from one plate to the other, initial and final plate being defined by the direction error on your particle. Please clarify these.

Comment: @TBissinger. I am sorry, I meant a positive charge eg +2nC and a negative charge like -6nC. and for the work i meant it will be like -20 mJ for negative.